# SASS: Content based on attribute

Tags: css, sass

How to make this work

```
&[val='#{$v}']:after{
  content: '#{$v}';
}
```

Want content based on attribute `val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [feature of CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18). No special Sass/SCSS syntax is involved.

```
&[val]:after{
  content: attr(val);
}
```